# fixing a corrupted SD card in linux

Tags: sd-card, clockworkmod-recovery, htc-desire, linux, twrp

My phone is a HTC Desire (model Bravo) and I previously rooted it (using tacoroot and revolutionary) and had the clockworkmod recovery (5.8.0.2) on it as well as the liquidsmooth v3.2 rom for the Desire.

I formatted the SD card in clockworkmod, choosing 2G for the extended partition and 128M cache. This still works after flashing CWM: `advanced` -> `Partition SD Card` -> `Ext Size 2048M` -> `Swap Size 128M` returns the happy message

```
Partitioning SD Card... please wait...
Done!
```

But then with the new ROM when I tested the camera, it said that there was no SD card present.

So I went back to the recovery and re-partitioned the SD card with different sizes (not sure how to go back to the original setting). Clockworkmod said that the re-partitioning was successful.

But after that first re-partitioning the SD card has not been accessible. This also means that I cannot install a new ROM (the browser invariably crashes in LiquidSmooth).

I have now installed the -very user friendly!- TeamWinRecovery version 2.3.1.1 to try and re-format or re-partition the sd card, but it says `E: unable to mount /sdcard` and `E:EXT + Swap size is larger than sdcard size`. That is not right because the card is 16G.

The following Linux command tell me that the phone is connecting with my computer:

```
$ fastboot devices -l    # during boot loader
SH07XPL04124             fastboot usb:2-1.1
```

Sometimes (but not always) when I attach the phone to the computer, I get the dmesg lines

```
[2076992.175291] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 70 using ehci_hcd
[2076992.280434] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bb4, idProduct=0c87
[2076992.280442] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[2076992.280448] usb 2-1.1: Product: Android Phone
[2076992.280452] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: HTC
[2076992.280456] usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: SH07XPL04124
[2076992.284078] scsi168 : usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0
[2076993.285389] scsi 168:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HTC      Desire           0100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[2076993.287105] sd 168:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[2076993.295416] sd 168:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

And in the File Manager (PCManFM 0.9.10) the device shows up as 'HTC Desire'. Clicking on it gives no result though -- the program asks which application should be used to open this file.

Following the dmesg lines, the command `gparted /dev/sdc` results in

```
Error opening /dev/sdc: No medium found
```

During the recovery session, I can `adb shell` but nothing is listed in `/proc/filesystem` or `/proc devices`. With `lsusb` I get

```
Bus 002 Device 083: ID 0bb4:0c87 HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.) Desire (debug)
```

During fastboot, `adb shell` returns an error.

On the phone, in the TWR file manager, I can go to the directories /sdcard (which contains a directory `/sdcard/TWRP` with a file `.twrps`) and `/sd-ext` (which is empty). Using `adb shell` I can also delete `/sdcard` and `/sd-ext` --it turns out they are just directories created during the mounting attempts. Trying to mount them again re-creates the directories but also says:

```
E:Unable to mount storage
E:Unable to mount '/sdcard'
```

I just cannot partition or format the sd card to a usable state again.

My suspicion is that the previous partitioning in CWM causes it to mount as a system directory (or something like that) so that it is not available any more for mounting as external storage.

Does that make sense?

And has anyone an idea how to solve this?

Comment: The full partition listing would be helpful here. Also, if it's an external SD card, you could use a card reader to check/fix it using a computer, best if that's running Linux (there are LiveCDs in case it's not) to correctly deal with EXTFS etc.

Comment: Since none of my partitioning programs can access the card I cannot give you a listing. A USB card reader for the SD card seems the best bet -- not sure what my chances are if the pratition table is fried. I will get one of those and keep you posted.

Comment: BTW the reason I wanted to re-partition the sd card was to be able to use app2sd etc. -- what partitioning would you recommend? (I understand that a bit needs to be FAT). I am using linux commands -- was thinking ext3 or 4 for the bulk of it.

Comment: The partition table isn't some kind of separate hardware, you can just clean the card of any partitions and format it back to normal.  Most devices let you move apps to the SD card without special partitioning, does yours not?

Comment: @MatthewRead that feature (native App2SD) was "removed" by many facturers with ICS and higher. // alle_meije: The *first* partition must be a primary and formatted FAT. What you put "further behind" shouldn't interfere.

Comment: @Izzy I have formatted the card in Windows now -- 1st primary is FAT32, 2nd primary is ext2 and there is a swap space of 128ish MB. Should that work with one of the newer custom mods?

Comment: I'd say so, yes. In the worst case, it should at least show (and use) that first primary partition (with all ROMs AFAIK). Swap might need the kernel to support it, though.

Comment: Well, fail once again. I must say that neither CWM nor TWR recoveries have been able to to anything with my 2 uSD cards - the original one from the phone and a new one bought last week. If I delete all partitions and let TWR try (`parition SD card`) and choose only 1024M of ext4 and 128M swap, it returns `E: EXT + Swap size is larger than sdcard size` followed by `E: unable to mount /sdcard` - CWM same story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that one is solved!

The problem was not the SD cards, but the fact that rooting etc. the Desire caused it to USB-brick. Never heard that before.

As Spezi77 advises in the presentation of his [CM11-for-Desire](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2549776) link, I switched to the [4ext](http://androidforums.com/threads/4ext-recovery-a-how-to.631481/) recovery, which has a special USB-unbrick function. Some sources also name fastboot commands that should do the same, but they did not work for me.

Long story short, I'm running Spezi77's version of CM11 on my Desire now!

Comment: switched to LiquidSmooth to get gapps to work http://my-orion.synology.me:8000/wordpress/?p=708